# Returning a Javascript Promise from $.ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, es6-promise

I am attempting to cast a $.ajax() statement to an es6 Promise and return the es6 promise.  The idea is that I will have an application layer of Create, Update, Delete calls to the Microsoft Dynamics Web API which return an es6 Promise so that I can reuse the Create, Update, Delete calls across multiple pages.  I've read through the [Google](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), and [David Walsh Blog](https://davidwalsh.name/promises) articles about es6 Promises as well as several SO questions, but I haven't been able to quite put together the details yet.

In my code below, when `ExpenseUpload.js` calls `expenseTransactionSetAPI.Create(newExpenseTransactionSet).then(...));` I see the execution getting to the `then()`, but nothing inside the `then()` is being executed.  I'm not quite sure what changes I need to make so that my code execution actually processes the `then()` and I'm not even sure if I am using es6 Promises correctly.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

### ExpenseUpload.js

```
"use strict";

requirejs.config({
    bundles: {
        'CCSEQ.WebAPI.js': ['Model/ExpenseTransaction', 'Model/ExpenseTransactionSet', 'API/ExpenseTransaction', 'API/ExpenseTransactionSet']
    }
});

require(["Model/ExpenseTransaction", "Model/ExpenseTransactionSet", "API/ExpenseTransaction", "API/ExpenseTransactionSet"], function (ExpenseTransactionModel, ExpenseTransactionSetModel, ExpenseTransactionAPI, ExpenseTransactionSetAPI) {

let file;

$(document).ready(() => {
    setupHandlers();
});

function setupHandlers() {
    $("#csv-file").change((e) => {
        file =  e.target.files[0];
    });

    $("#btnUploadFile").click(() => loadFile());
}

function loadFile() {
    Papa.parse(file, {
        complete: (results) => {
            ImportExpenseTransaction(results.data);
            console.log("import complete");
        }
    });
}

function ImportExpenseTransaction(data) {
    let newExpenseTransactionSet = new ExpenseTransactionSetModel.ExpenseTransactionSet();
    newExpenseTransactionSet.SetName = $("#UploadName").val();
    newExpenseTransactionSet.Month = $("#UploadMonth").val();
    newExpenseTransactionSet.Year = $("#UploadYear").val();
    newExpenseTransactionSet.ImportDate = new Date();
    newExpenseTransactionSet.Status = 100000000;        

    let newExpenseTransactions = new Array();
    data.forEach((expense) => {
        if (expense[0] !== "PR EMP ID") {
            let newRecord = new ExpenseTransactionModel.ExpenseTransaction();
            newRecord. = expense[n];  
            ... // Load other records like above
            newExpenseTransactions.push(newRecord);
        }
    });

    let expenseTransactionSetAPI = new ExpenseTransactionSetAPI.ExpenseTransactionSet();
    let expenseTransactionAPI = new ExpenseTransactionAPI.ExpenseTransaction();
    expenseTransactionSetAPI.Create(newExpenseTransactionSet).
        then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            console.log("Transaction Set Created");
            expenseTransactionAPI.
                Create(newExpenseTransactions[0]).
                then(() => {
                    console.log("Transaction Created");
                }).catch(() => {
                    console.log("failure");
                });
        }).catch(() => {
            (data) => {
                console.log(data);
                console.log("failure");
            }
        });        
}
});
```

### CCSEQ.WebAPI.js

```
define("API/ExpenseTransaction", ["require", "exports", "API/APIBase", "Model/ExpenseTransaction"], function (require, exports, APIBase_1, Model) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    class ExpenseTransaction extends APIBase_1.APIBase {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.ConvertToEntity = (data) => {
                let result = new Array();
                for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    let newRecord = new Model.ExpenseTransaction();
                    newRecord.[field] = data[i]["fieldName"];
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    result[i] = newRecord;
                }
                return result;
            };
        }
        Create(expense) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                $.ajax({
                    url: this.ExpenseTransaction,
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: JSON.stringify(expense.toJSON()),
                    success: (data) => { resolve(data); },
                    error: (data) => { reject(data); }
                });
            });
        }
        ;
    }
    exports.ExpenseTransaction = ExpenseTransaction;
});
define("API/ExpenseTransactionSet", ["require", "exports", "API/APIBase", "Model/ExpenseTransactionSet"], function (require, exports, APIBase_2, Model) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    class ExpenseTransactionSet extends APIBase_2.APIBase {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.ConvertToEntity = (data) => {
                let result = new Array();
                for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    let newRecord = new Model.ExpenseTransactionSet();
                    newRecord.[field] = data[i]["fieldName"];
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    result[i] = newRecord;
                }
                return result;
            };
        }
        Create(expenseSet) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                $.ajax({
                    url: this.ExpenseTransactionSet,
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: JSON.stringify(expenseSet.toJSON()),
                    success: (data) => {
                        resolve(data);
                    },
                    error: (data) => {
                        reject(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
        ;
    }
    exports.ExpenseTransactionSet = ExpenseTransactionSet;
});
//# sourceMappingURL=CCSEQ.WebAPI.js.map
```

Comment: Which .then() is it that you are seeing not get executed? There are a couple of different calls to the same function

Comment: @netpoetica the two `then()`s are subtlety different.  One comes from `expenseTransactionSetAPI.Create()` and one comes from `expenseTransactionAPI.Create()`.  Notice the **Set()** right in front of `API()` in one of the two calls.  I am seeing the problem with the first `then()` which is from `expenseTransactionSetAPI.Create()`

Comment: FWIW, I put together a jsbin showing this in action. I don't see anything wrong with your method of wrapping the AJAX call in a promise - it seems to execute correctly: https://jsbin.com/besexatone/edit?html,js,console

I suspect maybe there is an error being thrown by another asynchronous process elsewhere that's halting execution of your .then() maybe?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just return the [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) requests, it returns a promise-like Object.

> The jqXHR objects returned by $.ajax() as of jQuery 1.5 implement the
>   Promise interface, giving them all the properties, methods, and
>   behavior of a Promise

```
Create(expense) {
       return $.ajax({
            url: this.ExpenseTransactionSet,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(expenseSet.toJSON())
        });
}
```

Comment: According to [this](https://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/tag/jquery-deferred-broken/) that would return a jQuery deferred which can cause issues because the deferred do not follow the [Promises/A+](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec) specification.  I wan't to get an actual es6 Promises/A+ compliant Promise

Comment: I found [this](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/07/07/jquery-3-1-0-released-no-more-silent-errors/) post that indicates that as of jquery 3.0 deferreds are now Promises/A+ compliant.  I'll give this solution a try.

Comment: As  note, `Promise.resolve( thenableObject)` is the standard way of converting a  thenable into an ES6 promise constructed by the `Promise` constructor. The returned promise can be relied on to behave in accordance with standards, such as running promise reaction call backs asynchronously  and not fulfilling a promise with a thenable object.